# What is it called/named when I 'apply' parameters to a function like this

Tags: javascript

I've been a googling fool, but I just can't seem to find it.  What is it called/named when I call a function with a parameter like this:

```
(console.log)('test')
```

For context, I saw it when I started playing around with replacing the process.stdout.write for testing purposes (to make sure log is writing an error message to stdout) along the lines of: [Preston Guillory's gist](https://gist.github.com/pguillory/729616):

```
process.stdout.write = (function(write) {
    return function(string, encoding, fd) {
        write.apply(process.stdout, arguments)
        callback(string, encoding, fd)
    }
})(process.stdout.write)
```

Comment: That is an immediately invoked function expression. The parentheses are needed to make sure it is correctly parsed. You would not need it for `(console.log)`, only in function expressions.

Comment: `(console.log)('test')` doesn't have a name. The important part about the second example is not the first set of parenthesis but the function definition followed by "calling" `()`.

Comment: Note that what you're actually asking about (at the bottom of your question) is **not** what you have at the top of your question, which is identical to `console.log('test')`. (Unlike the similar-looking but very different `(0, console.log)('test')`.)

Comment: Thank you all :)   T.J., I suspected as such that might be the case, thats why I included the whole example.   And sorry for the dupes, but I did try and find it :)